# Image 1 becomes image 2 with sliding effect from left to right?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d, ccsprite

I would like to show a *second image appearing* while a "door" is closing on my character. I've got my character in the middle of the screen and a door coming from the left. When the door passes my character, I would like to have this second image appearing little by little.

So far, I've gotten by with fadingOut the character and then fadingIn my second image of the character at the same position when the door is completely closed, but I would like to have both of them at the same time. **(the effect that image 1 becomes image 2 when the door is sliding from left to right)**. Would you know how to do this with Cocos2d?

Here are the images :

at first, the character is blue, and the door is coming from the left :
[image]

Then, behind the black door, the character becomes red, but only behind this door, so it stays blue when the door is not on him, and will become completely red when the door passes the character :

[image]

---

EDIT : with this code, the black door hides the red and blue rectangles : (And if i add each of my layers at a different depth, and only use GL_LESS, same thing)

```
blue.position =  ccp( size.width*0.5 , size.height/2 );
        red.position =  ccp( size.width*0.46 , size.height/2 );
        black.position =  ccp( size.width*0.1 , size.height/2 );

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        [batch addChild:red z:0];
        [batch addChild:black z:2];

        glDepthFunc(GL_GREATER);

        [batch addChild:blue z:1];

        glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

        id action1 = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:3 position:ccp(size.width,size.height/2)];
        [black runAction: [CCSequence actions:action1, nil]];
```

Comment: This seems pretty localized. Can you give a general case?

Comment: do you mean something like behind the wall effect? I guess a picture can help too.

Comment: @Gajet I edited my post with images! ;)

Comment: @Byte56 I edited my post with images! ;)

Comment: Are you using cocos2d 1.x or 2.x? Also: Are the regions always rectangles or can they be arbitrarily shaped?

Comment: @bummzack i've got version 1.0.1, and the blue/red rectangle is actually my character, so it won't be a rectangle, but two different versions of my character

Comment: This looks like you want image clipping. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177751/cocos2d-iphone-sprite-cliping-mask-frame

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test this solution myself, but I think it should work theoretically. you need a little more googling to find out how to exactly implement it. also note that for the whole process you need to have DEPTH_TEST enabled.

1. draw player at depth 0
2. draw the wall at depth 2
3. change depth test function to MORE
4. draw the overlay (blue) player at depth 1
5. restore depth test function to LESS

while working with z buffer, what ever you draw will change the depth. Meaning when you start drawing player all it's pixels are marked as z=0. Later when you draw the door, all pixel that are draw above player will be drawn with z=2. At this point we change the [depth test function](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDepthFunc.xml). Depth function determines what are the conditions to draw a new colors in that specific pixel. As I said we change the Depth test function. It means from that point forward OpenGL will only draw objects if they are behind other objects. I guess you can now see where I'm going to. The blue rectangle is behind the wall but it's above the red one. So while drawing OpenGL should just skip all the pixels which are not behind the wall.

**note:** I've just noticed the default `GL_DEPTH_FUNC` value is `GL_LESS` so I've changed instruction 3 and 5

Comment: thanks, can you explain a bit more? the blue version (depth 1) will be above the red version (depth 0), then how will the red version go above the blue version just when the door slides?

Comment: @Paul it's done.

Comment: thanks Gajet! ( when you say "OpenGL will only draw objects if they are behind other objects." (so the depth notion is completely different from the "z" value, right? which would override every pixel drawn in a lower "depth".) So if i drew an Orange rectangle behind the red one, the red one won't be shown, just because the orange is the "last" object behind another? Also, why don't you just draw, in this order: at first, player red at depth 0, then player blue at depth 1, and finally the door at depth 2, then put depth test function to LESS, and slide the door to show the red one? Thanks again

Comment: @Paul as I said I didn't test that thing myself. I just knew you can change the openGL behavior towards z value, and that's all. If you think your algorithm will work you can try it, but I'm not sure if it's possible that easily. I mean in my opinion you should draw wall and original player in different depths to be able to draw the overlay correctly.